# PXE E52 proxyDHCP offers were received. No DHCP offers were received

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, bootp

Have a Lenovo laptop which i'm trying to capture an image from as a test (we are moving from HP as our std laptop) and i keep getting the PXE E52 error when trying to boot from LAN.  With things exactly as they are all the previous HP models are connecting ok.  I'm at a loss as to what to test, as its working for the HP kit and don't want to break that.

Note: DHCP server and WDS server are two separate boxes but on same scope, VLAN, etc. and the DHCP lease is not full.

Comment: We need more information - what TFTPD server are you using? what are you trying to image with?

Answer (score 2):

The device may be "rejected" in WDS. Try clearing your rejected devices list by running `wdsutil /Delete-AutoAddDevices /DeviceType:RejectedDevices`

Answer (score 1):

Your PXE server (proxyDHCP) is responding, but your DHCP server is not. Check the logs on the DHCP server to see if it's seeing the request from the client.